# Como Resgatar Dados Externos JSON

Tags: angularjs

Estou aprendendo AngularJs com o Apigility.
Estou tendo algumas dúvidas e acho que só consigo entender perguntando...

Eu tenho esse código aqui:

```
App.controller('ListaCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.id     = 1;
  $scope.dealer = "Teste";
  $scope.stars  = "5 Estrelas";
}]);
```

Como eu faço para resgatar um JSON externo em uma API ?

Eu estou vendo esse código aqui:

```
var noticias = $http.get("http://localhost:8888/dealers")
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
     });
```

Mas não estou conseguindo fazer ele funcionar. Estou colocando dentro do `App.controller('ListaCtrl')`. Não sei se está certo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para usar dentro do `controller`, você precisa passar o serviço de `$http` que está sendo usado, da seguinte maneira:

```
App.controller('ListaCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.id     = 1;
  $scope.dealer = "Teste";
  $scope.stars  = "5 Estrelas";

  /* Seu $http */
  var noticias = $http.get("http://localhost:8888/dealers")
      .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
      });
}]);
```

É a mesma lógica do uso do `$scope`, para poder utilizar o serviço, você precisar referenciar ele no `controller` a ser usado.

Complementando a resposta, o ideal seria você utilizar esse `$http` em um serviço, seja ele um `service` ou `factory`. Lógico que isso foge sua pergunta inicial, mas é a melhor prática. Tenha esse pequeno macete em mente:

- Controller -> O `controller` precisa utilizar os dados, mas não interessa ao `controller` como serão obtidos, só interessa receber os dados.
- Service -> Deve providenciar os dados para o `controller`, o que será feito depois não interessa, apenas interessa que ele forneceu os dados.

---

Exemplo do uso de factory para receber os dados no controller:

```
/* Sua Factory */
App.factory('minhaFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
    var factory = {
        obterDados: _obterDados
    }

    function _obterDados() {
        $http.get("http://localhost:8888/dealers").then(
            function(response) {return response;}
        );
    }

    return factory;
}]);

/* Seu Controller */
App.controller('ListaCtrl', ['$scope', 'minhaFactory', function($scope, minhaFactory){
    $scope.id     = 1;
    $scope.dealer = "Teste";
    $scope.stars  = "5 Estrelas";

    /* Seu $http */
    var noticias = minhaFactory.obterDados();
}]);
```

Comment: Vou testar daqui a pouco e já retorno com um FeedBack.

Comment: Eu imaginei que era usando Services ou Factory. Tem como você postar a melhor prática ?

Comment: Eu acabei de fazer o que você postou. Mas deu erro de Allow-Control-Access-Origin... acredito que por estar em outro domínio localhost.

Comment: Provavelmente, mas você pode resolver isso passando um parâmetro de headers no seu `.get()`.

Comment: Coloquei o header, mas não foi mesmo assim.

Comment: Tente especificar o arquivo com `.json`. Ps.: Editei a resposta para adicionar o factory

Comment: Ah... Não posso. O Apigility trabalha com URL amigável... coloquei /1 no final para pegar somente um. Vou ver se tem como fazer isso...

Comment: Beleza, mas o importante é que o controller funcionou! =D Agora provavelmente é alguma limitação ou método de uso de acordo com o seu ambiente de trabalho.

Comment: Mas foi bom. Eu entendi pelo menos a sua explicação. Agora preciso ver esse Header. Obrigado!

Comment: Eu dei um `console.log(noticias)` embaixo do `var noticias` e retornou undefined. Está certo isso ?

Comment: Tente com o uso do `.then()`